When launching website in localhost and testing the api of that application in Postman why it is showing "Certificate has expired"?
I was testing Opencart Application APIs in Postman. Application was installed in desktop and to enable the application Localhost is needed. I had to create a session to generate a token to start the testing of "Add to cart" functionality of Opencart. But when I send the session request in Postman the response is showing the localhost dashboard instead of showing the token in Postman response section.
And also Status saying "200 OK" but it also showing that "Certification has expired"
Now I don't understand why "Certification has expired" showing on in Postman response part.
Can anyone help me to understand this situation why it is happening? and How do I solve this issue?
